# SQL column cannot convert date/time

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table that has a column that records login and logout times for customers. On logout times, sometimes they will logout at midnight which sets the timer to read as '0' instead of like 12:00AM. Is there a way to allow an acception of this 0? or change to 12:00AM?

Here is my SQL Command that I use:

```
CREATE TABLE LogoutIncidents 
(
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] NVARCHAR(30),
    [Logout Time] NVARCHAR(30),
    [LogoutInc] NVARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO LogoutIncidents
    SELECT 
        loginlogout.[Name], loginlogout.[Logout Time],
        CASE
            WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, loginlogout.[Logout Time], Schedules$.StopTime)) BETWEEN 0 AND 4 
              THEN 0
            WHEN [Logout Time] = 0 
              THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS LogoutInc 
    FROM 
        loginlogout 
    JOIN 
        Schedules$ ON loginlogout.[Name] = Schedules$.Name
```

The error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 76
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help is appreciated as always.

Comment: It says the error is on line 76...which line is that?

Comment: INSERT INTO LogoutIncidents

Comment: You could try something wonky like `ISNULL(NULLIF(loginlogout.[Logout Time], '0'), '00:00:00.000')` in your DATEDIFF function.

Comment: You obviously have some value in your data that is NOT able to be converted to a date value. Hence the error message.

Answer (score 5):

There is pretty much just one thing to do: do not store a time or date in a string (varchar/nvarchar)!

Use an appropriate type instead, such as [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) or [`datetime2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) (if the logout also has a date component).

Comment: the data that is uploaded into the SQL server is from a TXT file that is auto generated from another server application. It imports this as such. but you're saying to change the column type from nvarchar to time on the table I'm trying to load into? "LogoutIncidents "

Comment: Yes, change the type in the table column, and use a conversion which fits the bill (using [`convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for instance, or if needed a specific scalar function which does work the way you need it). If you can do the conversion before inserting the data that may be even better (e.g. by the code that parses the text file, and then pass the date in as parameter).

Comment: Or if changing the table schema is prohibitive, add a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment but why not first do an update of the table to replace 0 with the corresponding time for midnight (presumably the current day?)

Example:

```
UPDATE loginlogout
SET [Logout Time] = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110) AS DATETIME)
WHERE [Logout Time] = '0'
```